# After Angular 16 upgrade, throws errors for library mydatepicker and angular2-virtual-scroll not compatible with Angular ivy

Tags: node-modules, ivy, angular16, ng-upgrade, angular-compiler-cli

I have upgraded my project from Angular 15 to 16
And im using these two libraries

```
"mydatepicker": "^9.0.2",
"ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
```

But on ng serve both these libraries throws

```
 node_modules/mydatepicker/lib/mydatepicker.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class MyDatePickerModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (mydatepicker) which declares MyDatePickerModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check 
if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the 
library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

```
This likely means that the library (ngx-virtual-scroller) which declares VirtualScrollerModuleis not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check 
if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the 
library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

Tried this script in Package.json as well

```
"postinstall": "npx --package @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.9 --yes ngcc"
```

Not working still same error cmg on ng serve.

Any way to make these libraries work with Angular 16